# How to select columns in SQL server 2008 using WHERE and IN, having 2 columns in the where clause

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, select, where

**How to select columns in SQL Server 2008 using WHERE and IN, having 2 columns in the where clause.**
Here is what I have, however I am  getting some error message.

```
select * from tbl
where (col1, col2) in (VALUES ('x1','y1'),('x2','y2'),....);
```

> Msg 4145, Level 15, State 1, Line 2
>   An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected, near ','.

Please advise.

Answer (score 1):

I would do something along the lines of

```
select * from tbl where col 1 in (x1,x2) and col 2 in (y1,y2)
```

Unless you are looking for specific combinations such as xy and y1 together, you didn't specify enough in your question.

Comment: Actually, I am having 2 columns and 100 rows in a xl sheet that needs to be queried against one table. Each row is a pair. All the 100 rows needs to be queried once against that table. Does it make sense now ?

Comment: Is there a reason you cannot simply import the Excel spreadsheet into a table and join against the 'tbl' for Spreadsheet.col1=tbl.col1, Spreadsheet=tbl.col2?

Comment: If you can't import it, you can always use OpenRowSet to the Excel spreadsheet and do the join that way.

Comment: This query is not equivalent to what the OP wants to do.

Comment: Hi Scott, I dont want to import the data into the table. All I need is just to run a select and find out whether all the records present on the system based on COL1 and COL2 pair.

Comment: The condition in this answer is equivalent to `WHERE (col1,col2) IN ((x1,y1), (x1,y2), (x2,y1), (x2,y2))` (all possible values of x combined with all possible values of y). The question asks something else.